# APIError(code=-2014): API-key format invalid

Tags: python, api, format, api-key, binance

call to action!

I am struggling in this:

[APIError(code=-2014): API-key format invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5pj7.png)

**Any suggestion?**
Many thanks

```
# Import libraries
import configparser 
from binance.client import Client


# Load keys from config file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_file(open(r'C:\\*****my_path****\\secret.cfg'))
test_api_key = config.get('BINANCE', 'TEST_API_KEY')
test_secret_key = config.get('BINANCE', 'TEST_SECRET_KEY')

#ping the server
client.ping()
#get the server time
time_res = client.get_server_time()

# Getting account info
info = client.get_account()  
# Get current products 
products = client.get_products()
#Get all coin info
info = client.get_all_coins_info()

print(info)
```

--- EDIT: ERROR OUTPUT

Here the error message in output:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\ssida\OneDrive\Documenti\GitHub\AI7XF205SS\getting_account_info.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ssida\OneDrive\Documenti\GitHub\AI7XF205SS\getting_account_info.py", line 16, in <module>
    info = client.get_account()  # Getting account info
  File "C:\Users\ssida\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 1822, in get_account
    return self._get('account', True, data=params)
  File "C:\Users\ssida\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 292, in _get
    return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ssida\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 242, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ssida\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 237, in _request
    return self._handle_response()
  File "C:\Users\ssida\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 285, in _handle_response
    raise BinanceAPIException(self.response)
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2014): API-key format invalid.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 1.952 seconds
```

HEre the snapshot of the error message showed me by python terminal > Pylance explain to me that is related on reportMIssing Imports (that i dunno whats mean but ok!)

[image]

Comment: Please post the error message as text

Comment: And make sure it is complete.

Comment: +++ edit @KlausD.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely 'TEST_API_KEY' or 'TEST_SECRET_KEY' are wrong or have the wrong format. I had the same problem because the keys were stored in the .env file with quotes

```
TEST_API_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

and after removing quotes, it worked.

```
TEST_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent few hours debugging right "signature" generation, checking time sync and getting such message.
found that it is required to put signature as last api query param:

not working: [https://...]?signature=..&recvWindow=..&timestamp=..

working order: [https://...]?recvWindow =..&timestamp=..&signature=..